# How do I find non-SSL problems on my SSL page?

Tags: ssl

I have a couple of pages on my WordPress site that need to run over SSL. I've installed the [WordPress HTTPS](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-https/) plugin and configured the pages to use SSL.

However, I'm still getting the error message that some of the items are coming over unsecured and that is a concern for some users. I've looked into the generated source code and I can see some items that are still going over non SSL channels, such as the following tags at the top of the page when I view source:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US"> 
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
```

The browser only gives me the generic error message about mixed content. How do I determine which resources are causing the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do exactly what you're doing: view the source of the offending page, and do a text search for "http://". Anything with this protocol is "insecure", and needs to be swapped to https. Common offenders are stylesheets, javascript, and 3rd-party widgets.

If you can't find any problems in the source, try using [firebug's](http://getfirebug.com/) "net panel". It lists all the requests a page makes, and you can scan through them to look for anything that starts with "http://" (even asynchronous requests).

If you're still stuck, post the URL of your problem page and I'll take a look.

Comment: I posted a comment to the other answer and then saw your mention of Firebug's panel. I'll have to check that out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The stuff you quoted are merely namespace definitions. They are not active links, are never downloaded by browser and I don't think SSL matters for them.

It is hard to say what else might it be without seeing complete page's source.

Comment: I've been digging a little more into this and it appears that I only get the mixed mode error when I'm logged in as an administrator. So I've refined things a bit more that way, but I guess I was curious if there was some kind of tool to diagnose this. Maybe I'd be better off asking something like this over on webmasters or something...

Answer (score 0):

## Using Firefox

Make sure you have Firebug installed.
Go to the firebug net panel, right click on the column headings and enable the "Protocol" column

[image: Firebug Protocol column in net panel]

Then click on the protocol column to sort by http/https

[image: Net column sorted by protocol]

## Using Chrome

The network pane isn't as useful in chrome, but you can still get this information from the error console.

Click the link to show console messages and you'll see a number of errors and warnings that include the URL of the insecure content.

[image: Chrome console showing http/https errors]

Answer (score 0):

Worth noting that I had the same problem with Chrome, and could not find any item that was being downloaded insecurely. Firefox and IE were quite happy with the page. The offending http reference, according to Chrome, turned out to be an old image that had been commented out!